# Pass associative array into smarty include so that it's properties are available as root data

Tags: templates, include, smarty

When using smarty's {include}, how do I pass an associative array into the included template such that the array's named indexes are accessible as their own {$var_name} variables?

E.g.:

```
$data = [
 'moo': 'true',
 'moreMoo': [
   'a': 1,
   'b': 2,
   'c': 3
 ]
];
```

In the base template I have:

```
{$moo}
```

This will output true.

Then I want to include another template:

```
{include file="myOtherTemplate.tpl"}
```

Then in the included template I want to pass "moreMoo" so that when the included template accesses {$a} it will output as 1.

Comment: That's not an object, it's an array. Which did you mean? It could make quite a difference to the approach...

Comment: I'm working on Smarty in both JavaScript and PHP and technically an array is still an object in JS (which was the mode my brain was in when writing the title), but I've updated the question :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know that was possible! Now I look, I see that your example is halfway between JS object syntax and PHP array shorthand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this is not possible. The way forward is to namespace your data for different sections so that you can grab the bits you need for the included templates. e.g.

```
var data = {
    'templateOne': {
        'somedata': true
    },
    'templateTwo': {
        'someOtherData': false
    }
};
```